# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' on Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to create a failable initializer for a class. My class will be initialized using input from a network request. Networks being unreliable, I want to create an initializer the checks for the presence on all properties, and for it to fail otherwise.

I am trying to make use of guard here, so please feel free to point any obvious mistakes in the approach:

```
public class JobModel {
    let jobId: String
    let status: String
    let toName: String
    let toAddress: String
    let description: String
    let fee: Int
    let jobDate: NSDate
    let fromName: String
    let fromAddress: String

    init?(job: [String:AnyObject]) throws {
        guard self.jobId = job["jobid"] as! String else {
            throw InitializationError.MissingJobId
        }

    }
}
```

The `guard self.jobId` line is failing to compile, with error:
`Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'`

Any ideas on how to correct this error?

Comment: Do you want to *fail* (i.e. return `nil`) or *throw* an error if the property is not present? That's two different things.

Comment: The error message seems to be misleading: The expression after the `guard` statement must have an boolean result or the evaluation result of an optional binding (`let` syntax). Consider to validate the input dictionary *before* calling the initializer.

Comment: @MartinR, I would prefer to throw an error, as the caller of the initialiser will know why the initialisation failed, context that the caller won't get by returning nil.

Comment: All stored properties of a class instance must be initialized before throwing from an initializer. So I agree with @vadian about this, in your case it would be more convenient to validate input before creating the instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

guard requires a condition that conforms to BooleanType. Simple assignment doesn't. You would need something like this.

```
guard let j = job["jobid"] as? String else {
    throw InitializationError.MissingJobId
}
self.jobId = j
```

However, then you'll get the error "all stored properties of a class instance must be initialized before throwing from an initializer." This is expected and documented in the The Swift Programming Language:

> For classes, however, a failable initializer can trigger an
>   initialization failure only after all stored properties introduced by
>   that class have been set to an initial value and any initializer
>   delegation has taken place.

Chris Lattner mentions the current behavior is undesirable here: http://swift-language.2336117.n4.nabble.com/Swift-2-throwing-in-initializers-td439.html