# UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey not there in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8, 3dtouch, xcode8-beta6

Recently in Xcode 8 beta 6 (8S201h), this has become a problem.

```
 UIApplicationLaunchOptionsShortcutItemKey
```

Here's the error :

[image]

Anyone else having this issue?

```
var performShortcutDelegate = true
if let shortcutItem = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.shortcutItem] as? UIApplicationShortcutItem {
    print("ok")
    self.shortcutItem = shortcutItem
    performShortcutDelegate = false
}
return performShortcutDelegate
```

Comment: Try using `guard` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33689933/ambiguous-reference-to-member-subscript-on-dictionary

Comment: no luck :( same error

Comment: So you're still getting the `ambiguous reference to member subscript` error? Your code looks correct as shown, so it might have something to do with the enclosing function. It's also possible you need to include the block `if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {}` around your shortcut code. More information/context would be helpful. :)

Comment: So I just realized you're not unwrapping `launchOptions`, meaning it's still of `Optional` type when you try to use it. You can't pull values from an Optional dictionary, because it's [not technically a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096293/assign-value-to-optional-dictionary-in-swift). That's likely the issue. I've updated my answer to reflect this, and included the enclosing function as well. Let me know if it works!

Comment: this still isn't working with Xcode 8 GM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constant has changed (see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationlaunchoptionskey/1622972-shortcutitem)). You also need to unwrap `launchOptions` before using any values it contains.

Enclosing function is included for context.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            if let shortcutItem = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.shortcutItem] as? UIApplicationShortcutItem {
                print("Shortcut: \(shortcutItem)")
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: If this is in [`application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623032-application), then the `launchOptions` dictionary is already known to have key type `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey`. So you can just use `launchOptions[.shortcutItem]`.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code and the function it's inside? (Ideally, please paste it as inline code, not as a screenshot.)

Comment: My problem was the migration tool who missed changing the `launchOptions` type. So basically check the `UIApplicationDelegate` for the correct method interface. Should be `launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil`.

Answer (score 1):

The launchOptions Dictionary type has changed in the function parameters to [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: AnyObject].

```
private func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Its work for me using Xcode8 , swift3

```
    //Check for ShortCutItem
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        if let shortcutItem = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.shortcutItem] as? UIApplicationShortcutItem {
        }
    }
```